# Mesh Network - Multiple APs - Indoor IT Equipment (Conesole, Switch, etc.) to Outdoor Pole Mounted APs

Tags: wireless-access-point, ground

I came across the same questioned asked (Posted below):

"Initial plan would be to just connect it like so:

INDOORS | OUTDOORS
[ Switch ] -----[SP1]------------ cat6 w/ PoE-------------------[SP2]--[ Access Point ]
|

However, they don't specify what to ground these to. I would assume SP1 would ground to the building's ground, into an outlet box. But what would SP2 would ground to? The pole? A grounding rod?

As I've researched this, I find again and again warnings not to add an extra grounding rod, because it can create a new pathway for nearby lightning strikes to travel into the building, on its way over to the building's ground, passing through the networking equipment along the way."

The full original post can be found here: [Does an outdoor PoE Access Point need seperate grounding?](https://superuser.com/questions/1762349/does-an-outdoor-poe-access-point-need-seperate-grounding)

The answer provided was to **not** provide a second ground that was not directly tied to the main grounding point. However, from what I have researched it is best to provide a ground at the APs that connect to the main ground via a jumper.

So from what I gather something like this:

INDOORS | OUTDOORS
[ Switch ] -----[SP1]------------ cat6 w/ PoE-------------------[SP2]--[ Access Point ]
| (Main Ground)-----------------------------------(AP Ground via jumper)

In my understanding, the APs when located far from the switch, need to be grounded at the APs then connected via ground (jumper) to the main ground. This eliminates ground strike issues where it hit near the AP but far from the switch and will help equal out the volts disparity from one end to the other.

The article can be found here: https://www.truecable.com/blogs/cable-academy/when-lightning-strikes-ethernet-data-cable-and-lightning-protection.

Could someone provide a more in-depth answer as to if this is correct, incorrect, or can be set up this way to help damage from direct ground strikes?

Thanks for any help/comments!

Comment: Did you check @RohidGupta's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1778022/330527) in the original posting?